# Node.js Getting the error TypeError: callback is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I can't figure out how to pass the object result back to the function.  I am trying to do a callback but it's not working.  What am I doing wrong?   Does anyone know how to pass a variable from a child function to a parent function? 
I also can't seem do do that as well.

```js
findOrCreate(fb_response, function(error, result) {
    if (error) {
        res.serverError(error);
    }

    return res.send(result);
});

// If no user create new user
function findOrCreate(fb_response, callback) {
    Users.findOne({
        email: fb_response.email
    }).exec(function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            return callback(error, null);
        }
        // if user does not exist
        else if (!result) {
            //create a new user
            createUser(fb_response, function(error, result) {
                if (error) {
                    return callback(error, null);
                }
                // re-start the find or create function   
                return findOrCreate(fb_response, null);
            }); // end of create new user function. 

        } // end of - else if (!record) 
        else if (result) {
            return callback(null, result) // this is the part that I am getting wrong
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is mainly with your

```
return  findOrCreate(fb_response, null);
```

as you pass the call the callback function as null and never checks for it to be non null when executing it. Try changing it to

```
return  findOrCreate(fb_response, callback);
```